# Nslookup - Querying my Internet Provider

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

I'm trying to `nslookup` all records of my internet provider, but it's returning "Result too large". I'm using the Windows `nslookup.exe`.

example:

```
nslookup.exe
>server ns1.brtel.com.br
>set type=ANY
>ls -d brtel.com.br > brtel.txt
ls: connect: Result too large
*** Can't list domain brtel.com.br: Unspecified error
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? this sounds like insanity

Comment: @Chopper3, that's the first (and necessary) step toward downloading the Internet.

Comment: In fact i'm trying to find all hosts that are connected(via cable modem) to my Internet Provider.

Comment: Providers generally won't let you do that.

Comment: @user141179, and why do you think you deserve to have all that information?  What kind of abuse to you plan on performing once you get it?

Comment: @user141179 why? and why do you assume this approach will work anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Most DNS Servers restrict the answer to a 512 Byte UDP Packet. If the response is bigger than that then you get the error you're looking at. The solution is either to request less domains at a time or get your provider to up the limit on DNS requests, which is a bit unlikely.